# docker-compose - resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I'm trying to build my ark server on my v-server. But I have problems to start my docker-compose container. Here is the YAML file:

```
version: '3'
 services:
   ark-server:
    image: 'turzam/ark:latest'
    container_name: 'ark-server'
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '7778:7778'
      - '7778:7778/udp'
      - '27015:27015'
      - '27015:27015/udp'
      - '32330:32330'
    volumes:
      - ./data:/ark
    environment:
      SESSIONNAME: "Raphis's Server"
      SERVERMAP: 'TheCenter'
      SERVERPASSWORD: 'pass'
      ADMINPASSWORD: 'password'
      TZ: 'Europe/Berlin'
```

When I start it up with `docker-compose up -d`

I get the following error message:

```
Starting ark-server ... error

ERROR: for ark-server  Cannot start service ark-server: OCI runtime create failed: unable to retrieve OCI runtime error (open /run/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/c919d8e4e2d51b934d561a928cfd55e0f7af07a2a3a0ac3d52b3c5ba3cea14e6/log.json: no such file or directory): runc did not terminate sucessfully: unknown

ERROR: for ark-server  Cannot start service ark-server: OCI runtime create failed: unable to retrieve OCI runtime error (open /run/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/c919d8e4e2d51b934d561a928cfd55e0f7af07a2a3a0ac3d52b3c5ba3cea14e6/log.json: no such file or directory): runc did not terminate sucessfully: unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

So how can I fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Your yaml syntax is wrong 
you can use this website to verify your yaml syntax : http://www.yamllint.com/

So your Yaml file will be like this :

```
version: '3'
services:
  ark-server:
    image: turzam/ark:latest
    container_name: 'ark-server'
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '7778:7778'
      - '7778:7778/udp'
      - '27015:27015'
      - '27015:27015/udp'
      - '32330:32330'
    volumes:
      - ./data:/ark
    environment:
      SESSIONNAME: "Raphis's Server"
      SERVERMAP: 'TheCenter'
      SERVERPASSWORD: 'pass'
      ADMINPASSWORD: 'password'
      TZ: 'Europe/Berlin'
```

Comment: If it really was wrong then docker-compose would not accept the compose file. The indention error in the post is certainly not the cause of the problem.

Comment: So what's the problem?